# Vue: How to run javascript code exactly when a <v-dialog> is rendered?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuetifyjs3

I've finally been able to encapsulate a Vuetify `<v-dialog>` in a custom component in Vue 3 Composition API. Below is the code for my `SignUpDialog.vue`component. It's also available in a [Vuetify Play playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

```
<script setup>
  import { onMounted } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({ modelValue: Boolean })
  const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
  function updateModelValue(value) {
    emits('update:modelValue', value)
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    /* Verbose code that initializes firebase ui auth....*/
    // ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig) 
    /* Fails with error: "Could not find the FirebaseUI widget element on the page." */
  })
</script>

<template>
  <h3>modelValue: {{ modelValue }}</h3>
  <v-dialog :model-value="modelValue" @update:model-value="updateModelValue">
    <v-sheet class="mx-auto">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>modelValue: {{ modelValue }}</v-card-title>
        <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
      </v-card>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<style scoped></style>

<script></script>
```

My goal now is to populate the dialog with content from [FirebaseUI's Auth SDK](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-web/#using_firebaseui%20for%20authentication). I'm not including the actual code here because it's rather verbose. Suffice it to say that it ends with a call to an SDK function that injects HTML into `<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>`.

I've tried running the initialization code in the `onMounted` event handler and that yields an error that says:

> Could not find the FirebaseUI widget element on the page.

I think this is because the dialog is hidden at the time the custom component is mounted and so the `<div>` does not exist in the DOM yet.

**My question is** - How can I use idiomatic Vue 3 Composition API to have the initialization code run as soon as the `<v-dialog>` is rendered so that it succeeds in injecting into the `<div>`?

Comment: It makes more sense to have code that relies on dom in the same component where the element belongs, i.e. <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"> and ui.start() have to be extracted to a component, then it can naturally follow the lifecycle of v-dialog

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you. So you mean I should extract to a Vue custom component that only contains the `<div>` and runs the `ui.start()` in a plain `<script>` tag?

Comment: You need to put it to onMounted in that component, similarly to how you tried in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VNode hook `@vue:mounted` on the element then use the handler to init the Firebase widget:

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({ modelValue: Boolean })
  const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
  function updateModelValue(value) {
    emits('update:modelValue', value)
  }

  function onContainerMounted(el) {
    //init the widget here
  }
</script>

<template>
  <h3>modelValue: {{ modelValue }}</h3>

  <v-dialog :model-value="modelValue" @update:model-value="updateModelValue">
    <v-sheet class="mx-auto">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>modelValue: {{ modelValue }}</v-card-title>
        <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" @vue:mounted="onContainerMounted">
          aa
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) sounds appropriate here. It can run code only once the dialog is rendered, which would be when `modelValue` is true, so you would watch that value.  I'm not familiar with the firebase SDK but in case it only needs to run once you can include a flag variable, e.g. `initialized` that can be used in an `if` to only run the code one time.

```js
let initialized = false
watch(() => props.modelValue, (open) => {
  if (open && !initialized) {
    /* initialize firebase */
    initialized = true
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you but `modelValue` is not defined as a `ref`. It's a prop and watching it is discouraged: "A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types. "

Comment: My mistake not noticing it was a prop, but you can definitely watch props because `props` is a reactive object.  I've updated my answer using a getter function which is perfectly allowed.